# Excel does not support datetimes with timezones. Porqué de repente?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, numpy, openpyxl

tengo desde hace mucho tiempo este script de python

```
print("DataFrame SCHEDULE")
print("\n",schedule,"\n")
print(schedule.keys())
DSchedule = pd.DataFrame(schedule)
print(DSchedule.dtypes)
NArchivo_1=str(AÑO)+"-AGENDA_TEMPORADA.xlsx"
filepath = Ruta_DirGP+NArchivo_1
DSchedule.to_excel(filepath, index=True)
# DSchedule.to_excel(filepath, index=True, engine='openpyxl')
end = time.time()
delta = end - start0
print ("Tiempo de proceso  %.2f s." % delta)
```

que funcionaba perfectamente, pero de repente genera este error:

```
    DS_xlsx.py:130
    DSchedule.to_excel(filepath, index=True)
    ValueError: Excel does not support datetimes with timezones. Please ensure that datetimes are timezone unaware before writing to Excel.
```

he probado con openpyxl , igual.
he probado con

```
DSchedule['EventDate'] = DSchedule['EventDate'].dt.tz_localize(pytz.UTC) 
DSchedule['EventDate'] = DSchedule['EventDate'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

nada tampoco.

*Versión de Python: 3.9.16 (main, Mar  8 2023, 10:39:24) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
*Versión de Pandas: 2.0.1
*Versión de NumPy: 1.24.3
*Versión de Openpyxl: 3.1.2

Por favor, alguien me puede aclarar algo??? creo que ya no entiendo nada.

Answer (score 1):

Te está diciendo que no quiere nada de nada con zonas horarias. Ninguna. Ni UTC ni ninguna otra. Prueba con

```
DSchedule['EventDate'] = DSchedule['EventDate'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Lo otro es que, viendo que al parecer tienes ya un dataframe pandas por ahí al comienzo de todo, podrías usar pandas para esta tarea y para guardar en el excel, como indican en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66196205/236345).

```
exwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(
    rutaAlArchivo, 
    engine='xlsxwriter', 
    options={'remove_timezone': True}
)
```

PD. Python está cambiando un montón últimamente. A medida que nos salimos todos de Python2, van a seguir cambiando muchas cosas. Que funcione hace tiempo no es garantía de nada ;)